# Corresponding LP problems to zero sum games

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, game-theory, nash-equilibrium

Given a zero sum game like this one :

\begin{array}{c|rrrr}
& A & B \\\hline X & 10 & 3 \\ Y & 5 & 9 \\ 
\end{array}

how do you find an equivalent linear program ?

I think the answer is :

minimize $ x+y $ 
s.t. :

$x \geq 0, y \geq 0$,

$ 10x + 5y \geq 1 $,

$ 3x + 9y \geq 1 $

but I'm not sure about this. How do you find that ? I've asked some PHD student but they didn't know either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the game is a zero-sum game, the equilibrium can be found by applying maxmin strategy.  (thanks to John von Neumann)
Let $p$ is the payoff.
$$\max [ \min [E(p|A), E(p|B)]]$$

To implement this in LP(linear programming)

> $\max G$
>   s.t.
>   $10 P_X + 5 P_Y \ge G$
>   $3 P_X + 9 P_Y \ge G$
>   $P_X+P_Y = 1$
>   $P_X, P_Y, G \ge 0$

Where $P_X$ : Probability to choose $X$, $P_Y$ : Probability to choose $Y$

Indeed,
$10 P_X + 5 P_Y$ is $E(p|A)$; Expected payoff when the opponent chooses $A$.
$3 P_X + 9 P_Y$ is $E(p|B)$; Expected payoff when the opponent chooses $B$.

---

I can change my formula to similar to yours.

$10 P_X + 5 P_Y \ge G$  divide $G$ both sides
$3 P_X + 9 P_Y \ge G$  divide $G$ both sides

And define $x = \frac{P_X}{G}$ and $y = \frac{P_Y}{G}$, then

$10 x + 5 y \ge 1$
$3 x + 9 y \ge 1$
And since $P_X+P_Y = 1$, $x+y = \frac{1}{G}$

Therefore, **$\max G$** is the same as **$\min x+y$**

It turned into

> $\min x+y$
>   $10 x + 5 y \ge 1$
>   $ 3x + 9 y \ge 1$
>   $x,y \ge 0$

If we look from the column player's point of view, the smaller the number in the table, the better (zero-sum).

That's why it will be  (the dual fo the previous LP)

> $\max a+b$
>   $10 a +3 b \le 1$
>   $5 a + 9 b \le 1$
>   $a,b \ge 0$

where $a = \frac{P_A}{G}$ and $P_A$ : Probability that column player chooses A and so on.

Comment: I am not sure to fully understand your argument. Could you please be more precise and explain the notation you introduced ?

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have fully understand the problem. Mathstack was lacking someone like you for optimization problems, thanks ! 
Can you please just precise this little thing. How do you know the condition $G$ is stricly bigger than $0$? It is an important condition because when you inverse $G$, maximizing $G< 0 $ is equivalent to maximizing $x+y = 1/G$

Comment: It is because all the payoffs in the table are positive and probability should be positive. $10 P_X + 5 P_Y \ge 0$  Since I am maximizing $G$ it will be the Minimum of {$10 P_X + 5 P_Y$,$3 P_X + 9 P_Y$}. And both of them are positive.

Comment: And, we, Optimization folks, are preparing to open the "Operations Research and Analytics" site in Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

Maximin strategy for zero sum game.

Since it is zero sum, the maximum for me is the minimum for my opponent, maximum for my opponent is minimum for me.

Since both of player are trying to maximize their own payoff, My opponent tries to minimize my payoff.

That’s why I will get the minimum payoff by my opponent. Under the condition, how can I maximize my payoff? I should maximize the minimum payoff.

In LP how to implement $max(min(a,b))$ is
$\max G$
S.t.
$a \ge G$
$b \ge G$

Think about it a while. How can I maximize $G$, while the constraints are satisfied? 
Only way is to maximize the minimum of $a$ and $b$.

Zero sum game LP formula
G : the minimum of expected payoff between opponent’s choice A and B

Comment: thank you for your answer. Reading it deeply a few times helped me understand it. I agree with you. However, in the possible answers I can give to this question, there are only answers of the type described in my question (min x +y ). How do you make a correspondance between the G you fixed to x and y ?

Comment: Let me understand what you meant by X and Y. I assumed the payoff table shows the payoff of player 1, who choose X or Y. And the player 2 will choose A or B. What did you mean by $\min X+Y$ ? I thought you use X as the probability to choose X.

Comment: mhmm in fact I don't really know. I think it is the good answer, but I'm searching why it is. In fact, it is an exercice I find on the internet, you can check it here : p7 https://www3.nd.edu/~apilking/Math10120/Lectures/Topic%2028.pdf

Comment: It took some time to figure out the formulation you referred. That is a little different than I learned.  I edited the first answer by adding how to convert my formula to your style formulation. hope it helps you understand the contents. in turned out that your answer was right.