# Solution of a LP, give the probabilities of a mixed strategy of a zero sum game

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, game-theory, nash-equilibrium

Given a zero sum game like this one :

\begin{array}{c|rrrr}
& A & B \\\hline X & 4 & 3 \\ Y & 2 & 5 \\ 
\end{array}
and the given LP :

minimize $ x+y $ 
s.t. :

$x \geq 0, y \geq 0$,

$ 4x + 2y \geq 1 $,

$ 3x + 5y \geq 1 $

If I know the solution of the LP is given by x = 3/14, y = 1/14, how can I find the optimal strategy for rows and the expected payoff?

Comment: The LP is for Row player.

Comment: I m going to read tomorrow your answer on the other post and see if I can now do it on my own :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a sequel of [LP for zero-sum Game](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3185407/corresponding-lp-problems-to-zero-sum-games/3186657?noredirect=1#comment6560441_3186657).

Here $x$ is $\frac{P_X}{G}$, $y$ is $\frac{P_Y}{G}$  and $G$ is the Maxmin payoff.

Therefore, $P_X:P_Y = 3:1$, $P_X+P_Y = 1$.
We can easily solve
$P_X$ = 3/4 , $P_Y$ = 1/4

Now, since $P_X = 3/4$ and $\frac{P_X}{G}$ = 3/14 then

$\frac{3}{4} = \frac{3}{14} G$
$G = \frac{3}{4} \frac{14}{3} = \frac{7}{2}$

$G$ is $\nu$ in the problem.

If you don't understand why, please read the previous one.